# determine if a point is to the left or right of a line, on a globe

Tags: geometry

I have three points that are on the surface of a globe.  I want to determine if one of the points lays to the left or right of a line that joins the other two points, when travelling in a certain direction down that line.

So, parameters are:

globe (x,y,z,radius)

journey_start (x,y,z)

journey_end (x,y,z)

point (x,y,z)

My reasoning so far has got me this:

*globe origin, journey start and end are three points on a great circle and describe a plane.  I want to know if the other point is **above** or **below** this plane.*

but I haven't managed to extend that to an equation.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Isn't the leftness/rightness dependent on the point-of-observation and the orientation of the observer relative to the globe?  Does the line segment, when extended in the direction of its starting point, always pass through the observer's head like William Tell's arrow through the apple? What if someone gives you a good spin and you start rotating around the axis that passes between your eyes, like a pinwheel? When you're upside down a point that what was to the left of the line becomes to the right.

Comment: right, why I described it as a journey to give indication of the direction - the vector - of the traveller, and as a globe so as to give a concept of 'up' from the view of the traveller.

Comment: You think of the North Pole as "up"?  I know a few kangaroos who might disagree.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversed_map

Comment: A fun link Tim, but I can't see how you jumped to the north-is-up thing.  From the perspective of the traveller, 'up' is away from the centre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the vectors S and E as the vectors from the center of the globe to journey_start and journey_end. Their crossproduct is the normal N of the plane in which S and E lie. This plane of course divides the globe in two hemispheres, which correspond to your left and right. You can subsequently calculate the inner product of this normal with the vector from the center to your third point. It's either positive (right), negative (left) or zero (on the same great circle)

Comment: given that my sphere origin happens to be 0,0,0, I have dot(cross(start,stop),point)

Answer (score 1):

Find the plane that the two points and the center are on, the parallel plane that passes through the third point, the offset between the two planes, the cross product of the two points and the center, and whether or not the direction of the offset is the same as the direction of the cross product.